# PrismaORM request error. How to fix that?

Tags: next.js, prisma

I am face with this error:

```
error - src\app\api\account\page.js (17:8) @ status
error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')
    at handler (./src/app/api/account/page.js:26:13)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
digest: "1374978740"
  15 |     }
  16 |   } else {
> 17 |     res.status(StatusCodes.NOT_FOUND).json({ msg: "Invalid Request" });
     |        ^
  18 |   }
  19 | }
```

This error pops up, when i try to fetch data from the server.

Here is my client-side code:

```
"use client"
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Link from 'next/link';


const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  button: {
    margin: "10px",
  },
}));

export default function NavBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const res = await fetch('/api/account');
      const data = await res.json();
            console.log(data)
      setUsers(data);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
            Budget App
          </Typography>
          <Link href="/account/login">
          <Button color="inherit" className={classes.button}>
            Login
          </Button>
                    </Link>
                    <Link href="/account/register">
          <Button color="inherit" className={classes.button}>
            Register
          </Button>
                    </Link>
                    <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
          
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is my Server-side code:

```
import { StatusCodes } from 'http-status-codes';
import {prisma} from "../lib/client"

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { method } = req;

  if (method === "GET") {
    try {
      const users = await prisma.user.findMany(); // Retrieve all users
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({users});
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({ msg: "Error" });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(StatusCodes.NOT_FOUND).json({ msg: "Invalid Request" });
  }
}
```

How to fix this error? I am struggle with this problem almost week trying to figure out why that error happen. Please give me a clue. I am using PrismaORM, Nextjs, and build user registration form.